# How to find a d3.js plot element by its connected data?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a d3.js plot that is made from an array of objects, such as:

```
svg.selectAll(".circ").data(dataArr) // dataArr is my array of objects
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("cy", function (d) {
        return d.y
    })
    .attr("cx", function (d) {
        return d.x
    })
    .attr("r", elemSize / 2)
    .on("dblclick", function (d, i) {
        itemWasClicked(d,i); // function to handle double click
    }
```

in the mentioned `itemWasClicked(d,i)` routine (where `d` is data of clicked element and `i` is index of it in array `dataArr`) I need to find the actual SVG element that was clicked and change its color.

How I could find a d3.js element by data attached to it? I do not want, unless necessary, to use attaching/searching by ID element. I only would do that if it is faster or there is no way to do otherwise.

Comment: Have you tried using `this` inside of your click event handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of the event handler `this` is a direct reference to the actioned element.

See [`selection.on` documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#on):

> The specified listener is invoked in the same manner as other operator
>   functions, being passed the current datum `d` and index `i`, with the
>   `this` context as the current DOM element.

So you can simply:

```
.on("dblclick", function (d, i) {
    changeColorOf(this);
}
```